# My Push method is not working and showing some error

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

my push method is not working. It is showing some error and I am unable to diGONOSE the error. can someone check what is the problem with my push method.

```js
console.log("Hello, World");

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

console.log(sum(2, 5));

let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");

btn1.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  let txt1 = document.getElementById("txt1");

  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");

  //notesObj=JSON.parse(notes);
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  } else {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }
  //notesObj.innerHTML="Array=[" + txt1 + "]";
  //var element ="notes.value";
  notesObj.push(txt1.value);
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
  //txt1.value=();
  console.log(notesObj);
});
```

Comment: What is the error u are getting when running the code?

Comment: script.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:23:18)

Comment: Have you tried debugging the value of `notes`? Perhaps it's the string `"null"`. You're also declaring `notesObj` as global (missing `let notesObj`) which isn't usually a good idea

Comment: yes I am declaring notesObj as string which will be get stringified after I give any notes in my html webpage. here notes is null until I haven't typed anything in my notepad text area(html webpage). After I write some notes in web I am declaring that this notes should get stringify in local storage

Comment: That's not what I asked at all. Do some simple debugging and add `console.log("notes", JSON.stringify(notes))` and let us know **exactly** what it displays

Answer (score 1):

The only way this can happen is if you have the literal string `"null"` stored in `localStorage`.

> ```js
> let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes"); // "null"
> if (notes == null) { // "null" ≠ null
>   notesObj = [];
> } else {
>   notesObj = JSON.parse(notes); // JSON.parse("null") -> null
> }
> ```

I would be more inclined to parse whatever value you have in storage and fallback to an empty array using the [*nullish coalescing operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```js
const notesObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")) ?? [];
```

This way if there's nothing in `localStorage` (`null`) or the literal string `"null"`, you'll always get an empty array.